# /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, websphere, ibm-was

I am running python file to start HTTP server in WebSphere but suddenly its searching java in some wrong location Then I stopped server and trying to start by startNode.sh shell script but its not starting server and giving same error its searching java in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java.

previously it was fine even I set the java class-path in bash_profile.

When I try to run the file ./startNode.sh or ./startManager.sh its giving error.

ERROR CODE:

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/startNode.sh: line 151: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java: No such file or directory.
```

How can I specify the path so web-sphere server can take it correctly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the startNode.sh script to figure out what it its doing.  That will probably explain the problem.  (I'm guessing it is something to do with environment variable settings.)

Comment: Did you manipulate these scripts or the installation root? Normally the path to java is not configurable and does not obey JAVA_HOME for WebSphere (classic).

Comment: I didn't change anything it was fine previously I am just setting JAVA_HOIME in all python scripts and it was working fine but suddenly its looking for path in AppServer Directory. that's  why I stopped the server but now I am not able to even start the server because I am getting this error when i am running to start the server.

Comment: Why are you trying to start HTTP server via python, instead just calling `/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/apachectl start` ? HTTP server has nothing to do with `startNode.sh` or `JAVA_HOME`. Maybe your script user doesn't have permissions to access `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java`

Comment: That is ok GAS But now  i am not able to start websphere server too not HttpServer. for starting WebSphere server also i am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths in WebSphere are managed by the [managesdk](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html) command.

The startNode.sh script not working seems to indicate the install was modified by either moving the JDK or changing a script to point elsewhere.

Comment: Actually by mistake my JAVA directory moved to another place that's why I was getting this error but after i again moved to previous location it's working fine.